# Speaker not working (Dell Vastro14 3000 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: updates

I am a novice user has recently got Dell Vastro14 3000 series with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as OS.

Just recently facing and issue post installing the Software Update.

Issue: Speaker not working but headphone is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sound Output device - it have probably been upgraded to HDMI or other HiFi device your Vastro support:
Click the small speeker on the Applicationsbar, choose Sound Settings, go to the output Devices Tab, select the Built-in Audio Analog Stereo. 
The Port is most likely set to headphones - which works!
Set it to Speakers!

If it still does not work check the Configuration Tab, make sure that Built-in Audio is connected to your Analog Stereo Whatever device!

You should hear your music through the inbuilt speakers - provided you have unplugged your headphones.